# Dropzone append dynamic attributes to #dz-remove

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, dropzone.js

I am trying to implement a removedfile on dropzone. I am using rails, to implement this I have to add an `id = 1` attribute to my dz-remove class.

This is my current code:

```
    var dropzone = new Dropzone ("#my-dropzone", {
        maxFiles: 50,
        maxFilesize: 30,
        paramName: "album[images][]",
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        uploadMultiple: true,
        autoProcessQueue: false,
        parallelUploads: 10,
        processing: function(){
                dropzone.options.autoProcessQueue = true;},
        init: function(){
              var thisDropZone = this;
              $.getJSON('image_list', function(data) {
                $.each(data, function(index, val) {
                      var mockFile = { name: val.name, size: val.size };
                      thisDropZone.emit("addedfile", mockFile);
                      thisDropZone.emit("thumbnail", mockFile, val.path);
                      thisDropZone.emit("complete", mockFile);
                    });
                });
              }
```

I have tried this code:

```
    success: function(file, response){
                $(file.previewTemplate).find('.dz-remove').attr('id', response.fileID);
                $(file.previewElement).addClass("dz-success");
            }
```

fileID is gotten from my picture controller:

```
if @picture.save
  render json: { message: "success", fileID: @picture.id }, :status => 200
else
```

It works but, when I refresh the browser the attribute `id = 1` is gone. I also want to separate my upload and edit pages.

I also tried to get the id value from json file with this code:

```
init: function(){
    var thisDropZone = this;
    $.getJSON('image_list', function(data) {
       $.each(data, function(index, val) {
           var mockFile = { name: val.name, size: val.size };
           thisDropZone.emit("addedfile", mockFile);
           thisDropZone.emit("thumbnail", mockFile, val.path);
           thisDropZone.emit("complete", mockFile);

           $(".dz-remove").attr("id", val.id);
        });
    });
}
```

Again this works and adds a permanent `id = 1` attribute to my html. But the appended val.id is constant. Example if I have 3 images:

```
<a href="javascript:undefined;" class: "dz-remove" data-dz-remove id="1">Remove</a>
<a href="javascript:undefined;" class: "dz-remove" data-dz-remove id="1">Remove</a>
<a href="javascript:undefined;" class: "dz-remove" data-dz-remove id="1">Remove</a>
```

my desired output is:

```
<a href="javascript:undefined;" class: "dz-remove" data-dz-remove id="1">Remove</a>
<a href="javascript:undefined;" class: "dz-remove" data-dz-remove id="2">Remove</a>
<a href="javascript:undefined;" class: "dz-remove" data-dz-remove id="3">Remove</a>
```

I also tried `$(".dz-remove").each` but the value is still constant instead of dynamic. I am also confused because when I do `console.log($(".dz-remove").attr("id", val.id))` The console values are appended correctly (`id=1, id=2, id=3`). On html all I get are `id=1`.

Comment: <a href="javascript:undefined;" class: "dz-remove" data-dz-remove id="3">Remove</a>

here class: "dz-remove", replace to =

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change $(".dz-remove").attr("id", val.id); to 
$(".dz-remove").eq(index).attr("id", val.id);

$(".dz-remove") return array of elements, u want add id to current, use eq(index of element)

Comment: Tried it, all id's are still the same id=1

Comment: try replace val.id to $(val).attr('id');
and in html after class u put colon, replace to '='

Comment: Okay Nevermind, it worked thanks a lot. My browser just cached and needed several refreshes.